# RubyMotion Android custom button

Tags: android, ruby, button, rubymotion

I am trying to create a button in my Android app that has a custom background and is centered on the screen. I have already done so using Android Studio, but now I have to do using RubyMotion. Here is how the button is supposed to look like this

[image: here]

Here's my main_activity.rb file for RubyMotion:

```
class MainActivity < Android::App::Activity
  def onClick(view)
    if @button.text == "hello"
      @button.text = "world"
    else
      @button.text = "hello"
    end
  end

  def onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    super

    relativeLayout = Android::Widget::RelativeLayout.new(self)

    @button = Android::Widget::Button.new(self)
    @button.text = "hello"

    @button.onClickListener = self

    relativeLayout.addView(@button)
    self.contentView = relativeLayout
  end
end
```

This simply adds a button whose text changes when I click it. But I can't find a way to center it on the screen and change its background. Using Android Studio, I created a custom shape as a drawable and then set the button background to that shape. Not sure how to translate that t RubyMotion code, or an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Does this achieve what you're looking to do?

```
class MainActivity < Android::App::Activity

  def onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    super

    relativeLayout = Android::Widget::RelativeLayout.new(self)

    @button = Android::Widget::Button.new(self)
    @button.text = "hello"
    @button.onClickListener = self
    @button.setBackgroundResource(
      self.resources.getIdentifier('android_normal', 'drawable', self.packageName)
    )

    params = Android::Widget::RelativeLayout::LayoutParams.new(
      Android::Widget::RelativeLayout::LayoutParams::WRAP_CONTENT,
      Android::Widget::RelativeLayout::LayoutParams::WRAP_CONTENT)
    params.addRule(Android::Widget::RelativeLayout::CENTER_HORIZONTAL)
    params.addRule(Android::Widget::RelativeLayout::CENTER_VERTICAL)

    relativeLayout.addView(@button, params)

    self.contentView = relativeLayout
  end

  def onClick(view)
    puts 'click'
  end

end
```

Comment: Hey Simon! This was a very old project and I longer have the setup to test it out. Thanks for answering though